# Python: Regex outputs 12_34 - I need 1234

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

So I have input coming in as follows: `12_34 5_6_8_2 4_____3 1234`

and the output I need from it is: `1234, 5682, 43, 1234`

I'm currently working with `r'[0-9]+[0-9_]*'.replace('_','')`, which, as far as I can tell, successfully rejects any input which is not a combination of numeric digits and under-scores, where the underscore cannot be the first character.

However, replacing the _ with the empty string causes 12_34 to come out as 12 and 34.

Is there a better method than 'replace' for this? Or could I adapt my regex to deal with this problem?

EDIT: Was responding to questions in comments below, I realised it might be better specified up here.
So, the broad aim is to take a long input string (small example:
    "12_34 + 'Iamastring#' I_am_an_Ident"
and return:
    ('NUMBER', 1234), ('PLUS', '+'), ('STRING', 'Iamastring#'), ('IDENT', 'I_am_an_Ident')
I didn't want to go through all that because I've got it all working as specified, *except* for number.
The solution code looks something like:
    tokens = ('PLUS', 'MINUS', 'TIMES', 'DIVIDE', 
          'IDENT', 'STRING', 'NUMBER') 
    t_PLUS = "+"
    t_MINUS = '-'
and so on, down to:
    t_NUMBER = ###code goes here
I'm not sure how to put multi-line processes into t_NUMBER

Comment: The code in your question doesn't make that much sense to me, but maybe applying this pattern would solve your issue: `([0-9]+_*)+`

Comment: Note that when you edit your question, people don't get notified like they do when you comment on their answers.

Comment: +1 Ivc, which is why I only found the edit now. The best way is to edit the question **and** ping the person you need to see it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean and why you need regex, but maybe this helps

```
In [1]: ins = '12_34 5_6_8_2 4_____3 1234'

In [2]: for x in ins.split(): print x.replace('_', '')
1234
5682
43
1234
```

EDIT in response to the edited question:

I'm still not quite sure what you're doing with tokens there, but I'd do something like (at least it makes sense to me:

```
input_str = "12_34 + 'Iamastring#' I_am_an_Ident" 
tokens = ('NUMBER', 'SIGN', 'STRING', 'IDENT')
data = dict(zip(tokens, input_str.split()))
```

This would give you

```
{'IDENT': 'I_am_an_Ident',
 'NUMBER': '12_34',
 'SIGN': '+',
 'STRING': "'Iamastring#'"}
```

Then you could do

```
data['NUMBER'] = int(data['NUMBER'].replace('_', ''))
```

and anything else you like.

P.S. Sorry if it doesn't help, but I really don't see the point of having `tokens = ('PLUS', 'MINUS', 'TIMES', 'DIVIDE', 'IDENT', 'STRING', 'NUMBER')`, etc.

Comment: I need regex because it's an assignment that says "use regex"; and I like your solution, I'm just not sure how to implement it in a block of code which is defining tokens, so:
t_PLUS = "\+"

t_MINUS = '-'
etc, which seems to my eyes to restrict me to 1-line solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about tokens; what does your code have to do, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
a='12_34 5_6_8_2 4___3 1234'
>>> a.replace('_','').replace(' ',', ')
'1234, 5682, 43, 1234'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing of your question is a little bit unclear. If you don't care about input validation, the following should work:

```
input = '12_34 5_6_8_2 4_____3 1234'
re.sub('\s+', ', ', input.replace('_', ''))
```

If you need to actually strip out all characters which are not either digits or whitespace and add commas between the numbers, then:

```
re.sub('\s+', ', ', re.sub('[^\d\s]', '', input))
```

...should accomplish the task. Of course, it would probably be more efficient to write a function that only has to walk through the string once rather than using multiple `re.sub()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing something like:

```
>>> data = '12_34 5_6_8_2 4_____3 1234'
>>> pattern = '[0-9]+[0-9_]*'
>>> re.findall(pattern, data)
['12_34', '5_6_8_2', '4_____3', '1234']
re.findall(pattern.replace('_', ''), data)
['12', '34', '5', '6', '8', '2', '4', '3', '1234']
```

The issue is that `pattern.replace` isn't a signal to `re` to remove the `_`s from the matches, it *changes your regex* to: `'[0-9]+[0-9]*'`. What you want to do is to do `replace` on the results, rather than the pattern - eg,

```
>>> [match.replace('_', '') for match in re.findall(pattern, data)]
['1234', '5682', '43', '1234']
```

Also note that your regex can be simplified slightly; I will leave out the details of how since this is homework.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you *really* have to use `re` and only `re`, you *could* do this:

```
import re

def replacement(match):
    separator_dict = {
        '_': '',
        ' ': ',',
    }
    for sep, repl in separator_dict.items():
        if all( (char == sep for char in match.group(2)) ):
            return match.group(1) + repl + match.group(3)

def rec_sub(s):
    """
    Recursive so it works with any number of numbers separated by underscores.
    """
    new_s = re.sub('(\d+)([_ ]+)(\d+)', replacement, s)
    if new_s == s:
        return new_s
    else:
        return rec_sub(new_s)
```

But that epitomizes the concept of overkill.